# Certificate error

Tags: ssl, https, ssl-certificate

Have a little certificate error related question.
I have this domain www.coachba.se and I bought a SSL certificate for it. That works fine and browser gives no error whether on http or https.
However, when a user types in coachba.se on the browser(www is missing), it generates a certificate warning to user. The domain on browser is https://coachba.se
and once it gives the warning and the user accepts the warning the site comes just as it should. 
However this warning bothers me. I was wondering if there's a fix to this or do I have no choice but to buy a new certificate?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The certificate has been registered for www.coachba.se and only that will work. When the user goes to coachba.se, the error will be displayed as the certificate is not registered for this URL.

The 2 solutions are;

Get a wildcard SSL certificate (*.coachba.se)

Get a specific SSL certificate for coachba.se

Comment: No, it doesn't work for the domain itself. It needs a SAN for `coachba.se` in addition to `*.coachba.se` if you want the domain name without any prefix at all. (See RFC 2818 Section 3.1 or RFC 6125, that's also how it works in practice.)

Comment: @bruno A wildcard SSL for *.domain.tld will cover any host and the domain itself. I know because I use these on a number of sites in the same manner. The only caveat on this being that I used rapidssl.

Comment: @Bruno Not wanting to sound pedantic, but I know it works as I can see it here; http://www.cwb-solutions.co.uk/ssl.png. Unfortunately, those RFCs do not explicitly state that domain.tld will not work as far as I can see.

Comment: Show a screenshot of the 'Subject Alternative Name' entry in the Details tab if you want to prove your point.

Comment: Yes, as I was saying, and as the specs say, you have an entry for the name without any prefix: that's the one that's used for `domain.tld`.

Comment: @Bruno. Okay, but my comment above is accurate. An SSL certificate for *.domain.tld (which went in the certificate request) with cover both www.domain.tld and domain.tld. I am unsure as to what are you trying to say...

Comment: Not really, it really depends on the CA. Not all CAs that issue cert for `*.domain.tld` (or `www.domain.tld`) will also add the SAN entry for `domain.tld` too. Some do it for free, some do it for an extra fee. You just can't assume it will be the case.

Comment: Okay, but by your own statement preceding this, all wildcard SSL certificates are capable of supporting both *.domain.tld and domain.tld. Those that don't by default, will for a fee. Still not sure what your point is, but never mind, I have learnt something (don't argue on the internet, it's pointless)

Comment: You're right, my initial comment wasn't clear. I meant that it's not because the cert has `*.domain.tld` that makes it work for `domain.tld`, but because it's jointly issued for `domain.tld` (since the `*.domain.tld` has no influence on `domain.tld` itself, hence "*Get a wildcard SSL certificate (`*.coachba.se`)*" was unrelated, without the `domain.tld` SAN). You could in principle have a cert for `*.domain1.tld` and `domain2.tld`. I've heard some clients had trouble with certs with wildcard and non-wildcard SANs, but I haven't noticed it myself (and the specs are not against that AFAIK).

Answer (score 0):

Normally CA issue certificates for www.domain.com and domain.com . You might need to contact CA support and ask them how to replace the certificate to cover both variants. Also, this question is offtopic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry, but you need to buy a new certificate, this is stuff of web browser because your certification entity is not well known.